# OmegaConf: convert dict into List of Objects

Tags: python, omegaconf

I am trying to automatically convert

```py
from omegaconf import OmegaConf
s = """
nodes:
  node1:
   group: standard
   status: online
  node2:
   group: small
   status: online
  node3:
   group: standard
   status: offline
"""
```

into a list of nodes, where "node1/2/3" is the name of the node:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List

@dataclass
class Node:
  name: str
  group: str
  status: str

@dataclass
class Config:
  nodes: List[Node]
```

with

```py
conf = OmegaConf.create(s)
schema = OmegaConf.structured(Config)
merged_conf = OmegaConf.merge(schema, conf)
```

Is there a mechanism in place for this?
If I try it out-of-the-box I get

```
omegaconf.errors.ConfigTypeError: Cannot merge DictConfig with ListConfig
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is telling you that you are attempting to merge a dictionary with a List, which is not supported.
Your schema says that nodes is a `List[Node]`, but your YAML string contains a mapping (YAML terminology for a dictionary).

Either change your schema to indicate that nodes is a Dict:

```py
@dataclass
class Config:
  nodes: Dict[str, Node]
```

Or change your YAML string to contain a list:

```py
s = """
nodes:
 - group: standard
   status: online
 - group: small
   status: online
 - group: standard
   status: offline
"""
```

Comment: Yes, this is my current workaround, but it does not feel quite right.
Naively, I would like something with semantics closer to real English, e.g.
````yaml
nodes:
  ci001.example.com:
    attribute1: blah
   etc
```

i.e. "my node ci001.example.com has the attributes x,y,z" - closer to English than a list

Comment: This might help have a dict that is accessed as a list:
https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.1_branch/custom_resolvers.html#oc-dict-keys-value